# How to upgrade a struct in a UUPS upgrade pattern?

Tags: solidity, contract-upgrading

Let's say I have an upgradable contract (from openzeppelin UUPS wizard in this case) with a mapping address to struct like below:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.20;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable/access/OwnableUpgradeable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable/proxy/utils/Initializable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable/proxy/utils/UUPSUpgradeable.sol";

struct StructureV1 {
    uint256 param1;
    uint256 param2;
    uint256 param3;
}
 

contract MyContractV1 is Initializable, OwnableUpgradeable, UUPSUpgradeable {
    mapping (address => StructureV1) myMapping;

    /// @custom:oz-upgrades-unsafe-allow constructor
    constructor() {
        _disableInitializers();
    }

    function initialize(address initialOwner) initializer public {
        __Ownable_init(initialOwner);
        __UUPSUpgradeable_init();
    }

    function _authorizeUpgrade(address newImplementation)
        internal
        onlyOwner
        override
    {}
}
```

If in an upgrade of `MyContractV1` I also wanted to use a V2 version of `StructureV1`, with for example a fourth parameter `uint256 param4;`, is it possible to just modify `myMapping` to `mapping (address => StructureV2) myMapping;`? Or would I need to add another mapping after the first one to store the new variables of `StructureV2`?

Thanks for the help!